# ¿Es redundante la expresión "suele ser frecuente"?

Tags: definiciones, modismos

## Español

He oído a menudo la expresión “suele ser frecuente”. ¿Es redundante? ¿Suena bien a pesar de la redundancia? ¿O bien suena mal y sería mejor decir solo “es frecuente”?

**Por ejemplo:**

> Suele ser frecuente que al dejar el tabaco se ganen unos kilos.

---

## English

I have often heard the expression "*suele ser frecuente*." Is it redundant? Does it sound okay despite the redundancy, or does it sound awkward and would it be better to say "*es frecuente*"?

**For example:**

> Suele ser frecuente que al dejar el tabaco se ganen unos kilos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La RAE menciona en [la entrada para soler](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=soler) lo siguiente:

> soler2. (Del lat. solēre).
>
> 1. intr. defect. Dicho de un ser vivo: Tener costumbre.
> 2. intr. defect. Dicho de un hecho o de una cosa: Ser frecuente.

Fijándonos en la segunda acepción, vemos que *soler* significa, cuando se hace referencia a un hecho, lo mismo que *ser frecuente*, así que sí, *suele ser frecuente* es redundante y podría usarse tan solo *es frecuente*; sin embargo, las expresiones *suele ser lo más frecuente*/ *suele ser lo menos frecuente* son empleadas frecuentemente en el DPD.

Aunque *suele ser frecuente* sea redundante, es de uso tan extendido que yo no la consideraría como una expresión incorrecta; en el ejemplo concreto, tanto

> Suele ser frecuente que al dejar el tabaco se ganen unos kilos.

como

> Es frecuente que al dejar el tabaco se ganen unos kilos.

se pueden utilizar, aunque yo preferiría la segunda.

Comment: ¿Podemos decir, por tanto, que la expresión "suele ser frecuente" suele ser frecuente?

Comment: Y sin embargo, que aunque sea redundante como parece ser, no significa que esté mal dicha, que es lo que se pregunta al fin y al cabo. Yo diría que es una expresión que empleamos corrientemente y se ha quedado así.

Comment: @JoulSauron jeje; sí, podemos decirlo. De hecho, en un principio pensé escribir exactamente eso en mi respuesta pero finalmente me arrepentí.

Comment: @JoulSauron he editado mi respuesta añadiendo una pequeña nota sobre lo extendido del uso de la expresión. Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

> Suele ser frecuente que al dejar el tabaco se ganen unos kilos.

To me (Argentina) it is clearly redundant, and it sounds ugly. Actually, I wouldn't say I hear that expression usually.

Correct (and natural) is:

> Es frecuente que al dejar el tabaco se ganen unos kilos.

or:

> Suele suceder que al dejar el tabaco se ganen unos kilos.

(or "suele ocurrir" or "suele pasar" or "suele darse el caso de que...")